# ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, progressdialog

I can't use a progress dialog in a `Fragment`. I tried using a progress dialog in an `Activity`, however, and it worked.

Here's part of my code:

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
          super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
          final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
               true);
          pd.setCancelable(false);
          pd.setTitle("Please wait");
          pd.setMessage("Page is loading..");
          pd.show();
      }
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          view.loadUrl(url);
          return true;
      }
```

The error is:

```
The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type
ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments 
(CommunityFragment.MyCustomWebViewClient, String, String, boolean)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
           true);
```

`this` is not a valid context. Use `ActivityName.this` if it's an `Activity`. If it's a `Fragment` use `CommunityFragment.this.getActivity()`.

Comment: ok awesome worked with: CommunityFragment.this.getActivity() great thanks to both of you guys

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",
           true);
```

to:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(super.getActivity(), "", "Loading...",
           true);
```

When using fragments, you need to provide the context of the parent activity.

Comment: thanks for your 2 answers but still wont work: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type WebViewClient

Comment: in that case you would need to pass an activity's context to this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a constructor and pass the parent activity as a parameter when you call this class.

Here's an example:

```
Activity activity;
public MyCustomWebViewClient (Activity _activity) {
    this.activity = _activity;
}
```

Then use it:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading...",
           true);
```